# Simple validates_length_of yields unexpected NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, controller

I have a message form which uses validates_length_of in the model to limit the length of the message.

```
validates_length_of   :content, :maximum => 1024
```

I "tested" this by entering 5k or so characters and submitted the form. But I get this NoMethodError:

```
NoMethodError in Messages#create

Showing app/views/messages/_messages.html.erb where line #1 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%- for message in @messages -%>
2:   <div class="message">
3:     <%= link_to message.title, message %>
....
```

Messages#index:

```
def index
  @title = "chat"
  @messages = Message.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 8, :order => "updated_at DESC" 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

Messages#create:

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @message.save
      record_post_time
      flash[:notice] = "Created \"#{@message.title}\""
      format.html { redirect_to(messages_url) }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "index" }
    end
  end
end
```

_messages.html.erb: (super ugly and needs major refactor)

```
<%- for message in @messages -%>
  <div class="message">
    <%= link_to message.title, message %>

    <%- if message.name.empty? -%>

    <%- else -%>   
      <span class="name">
        by 
        <%- if message.email.blank? -%>
          <%=h message.name %>
        <%- else -%>
          <a href="mailto:<%= message.email %>"><%=h message.name %></a>
        <%- end -%>
      </span>
    <%- end -%>

    <span class="time">
      active &#32;<%= timeago(message.updated_at) %>
    </span>

    <%- if message.comments.empty? -%>
      <span class="reply">
        <%= link_to 'reply', :controller => 'messages', :action => 'show', :id => message %>
      </span>
    <% else %>
      <span class="reply">
        <%= link_to pluralize(message.comments.count, 'reply'), :controller => 'messages', :action => 'show', :id => message %>
      </span>
    <%- end -%>

    <p><%= sanitize message.content,
 :tags => %w(a embed img object p param),
 :attributes => %w(allowfullscreen allowscriptaccess href name src type value) %></p>

    <% unless controller.controller_name == "tags" %>
      <%- unless message.tag_list.nil? || message.tag_list.empty? -%>
        <% message.tags.each do |t| %>
          <div class="tag"><%= link_to t.name.titleize, tag_path(t) %></div>
        <% end %>
      <%- end -%>
    <% end %>

    <%- unless message.comments.empty? -%>
      <div class="comments">
        <%= render :partial => message.firstcomments %>
        <%- if message.comments.count >= 4 -%>
          <%= link_to 'more...', :action => 'show', :id => message %>
        <%- end -%>
      </div>
    <%- end -%>
  </div>
<%- end -%>
```

I am not sure what exactly is going on here. Any help would be appreciated (even with the partial refactor). Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: where are you declaring your @messages variable? that's the one that's raising a nil

Comment: @messages is in messages#index. I updated the question to show that code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi When you entered 5k or so characters the `Message` become invalid record so on create worked `else` condition

```
else
  format.html { render :action => "index" }
end
```

you have render here `render` doesn't execute code inside action it just renders text file with your current data You haven't assigned `@messages` inside your `create` action (I suppose you also haven't done it in `new`) so it is `nil` when you render the `index` 
You should initialize it inside `new` or `create` or change `render 'index'` to `render 'new'`

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure why it was changed to index.